# How to dynamically import multiple Vue.js components at once?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to import multiple components from a folder conditionally. The first example works, but I need to get it working conditionally like in the last example that doesn't work. Otherwise I'd have to always go and change which components should import manually, after adding one to the project folder.

I've also tried wrapping the imports into a function, but I can't get the `import * as components` syntax to work. Importing one component works fine, but not with * `return () => import * as components '@/components/index'`

**This works**

```js
import * as components from '@/components/index'

export default {
  components: {
    ...loadedComponents
  }
}
```

**index.js and electronIndex.js**

```js
export {
  default as one
}
from './One.vue'
export {
  default as two
}
from './Two.vue'
```

**This of course doesn't work, but demonstrates what I need**
I also tried importing conditionally via functions like stated above, but can't get that to work either.

```js
const IPC = window.ipcRenderer

if (IPC) {
  import * as components from '@/components/electronIndex'
} else {
  import * as components from '@/components/index'
}

export default {
  components: {
    ...loadedComponents
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW your 1st and last example are exactly same. What you are looking for is [require.context](https://v4.webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext)

Comment: Try 
````
const Comp1 = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "comp1" */ '@components/Comp1');
const Comp2 = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "comp2" */ '@components/Comp2');

export default {
 components: {
  Comp1,
  Comp2,
 },
}
````